# Delete table is not working in SQL automate using dacpac in Azure pipeline

Tags: sql, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm trying to deploy the SQL changes using build and release pipeline in Azure using dacpac. Creating and updating the table is working as expected using the release. But when i try to delete the database, it's not working even though my release is succeeded.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It worked after adding /p:DropObjectsNotInSource=true